# Como copiar div do iframe para o pai? (replicar) pode ser usando ajax, jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, div, iframe

Tenho um index.php que faz um post em conteudo.php, e pega o resultado e escreve na div #conteudo dentro de index.php.

Post:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(this).on('load',function(){
  
  var dadosLink = 'nada';
  
  $.ajax({
   
   url:'conteudo.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data:{ dados:dadosLink},
   success: function(data)
    {
    
    $("#conteudo").html(data);
    
    }, 
    
    error: function(data)
    
    {
    $("#conteudo").html(data);
     }
   
  });
  
  });


   </script>
```

no conteudo. php, tenho:

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/Gymo.php'); 
$aba = $_POST['dados'];

 if ($aba == "nada") {
 
 echo "
 <IFRAME name=Destaques frameBorder=0 style=\"overflow: scroll; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;\"  scrolling=auto src=\"inicio.php?dados=".$aba."&mercado=".$mercado."&email=".$email."\">
<div align=\"center\"></div>
</IFRAME>

 
 ";
?>
```

dentro do iframe inicio.php, tenho:

```html
<div class = "conteudo" id = "conteudo"> Quero replicar esta div para index.php com o mesmo id </div>
```

Minha questão: Como fazer para que o conteudo desta div contida no iFrame seja passada para a div #conteudo contida no index.php, substituindo os valores dela, seja eles quais forem?

Esta ação teria que acontecer ao ativar a função ajax do iframe: "$(this).on('load',function()..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa pegar todo o conteúdo que vem dentro do iframe, nesse caso é sua `div`.

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
var iframeContent = $(data).text(); // aqui vai retornar todo conteúdo dentro do iframe
```

Após isso, pegue todo o conteúdo que está dentro da sua `div` do `iframe` e coloque na `div` de destino.

```
var divContent = $(iframeContent).text(); // aqui temos todo o conteúdo da div do iframe

$("#conteudo").empty().html(divContent); // limpando a div de destino e colocando o conteúdo da div do iframe.
```

Comment: Obrigado. Editei minha pergunta para ficar mais clara. Tentei desta forma acima mas não consegui, talvez com algum exemplo mais passo a passo eu consiga entender, peço desculpas por ser meio newbie.

Comment: É só colocar o conteúdo da resposta dentro do seu success: function(data) {}, talvez eu também não tenha entendido muito bem a pergunta.